# hide entries in html select field based on another select field

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have 2 select fields in my html form.  one is for pick up ready time and one is for latest pickup time.

```
<label>What is the earliest Pickup time?</label><select name='PickupTime' required>
    <option value='' selected='selected'>(Select a Time)</option> 
    <option value='08:00:00'>8:00 AM</option>
    <option value='08:30:00'>8:30 AM</option>
    <option value='09:00:00'>9:00 AM</option>
    <option value='09:30:00'>9:30 AM</option>
    <option value='10:00:00'>10:00 AM</option>
    <option value='10:30:00'>10:30 AM</option>
    <option value='11:00:00'>11:00 AM</option>
    <option value='11:30:00'>11:30 AM</option>
    <option value='12:00:00'>12:00 PM</option>
    <option value='12:30:00'>12:30 PM</option>
    <option value='13:00:00'>1:00 PM</option>
    <option value='13:30:00'>1:30 PM</option>
    <option value='14:00:00'>2:00 PM</option>
</select>
<label>What is the latest Pickup time?</label><select name='CloseTime' required>
    <option value='' selected='selected'>(Select a Time)</option> 
    <option value='10:00:00'>10:00 AM</option>
    <option value='10:30:00'>10:30 AM</option>
    <option value='11:00:00'>11:00 AM</option>
    <option value='11:30:00'>11:30 AM</option>
    <option value='12:00:00'>12:00 PM</option>
    <option value='12:30:00'>12:30 PM</option>
    <option value='13:00:00'>1:00 PM</option>
    <option value='13:30:00'>1:30 PM</option>
    <option value='14:00:00'>2:00 PM</option>
    <option value='14:30:00'>2:30 PM</option>
    <option value='15:00:00'>3:00 PM</option>
    <option value='15:30:00'>3:30 PM</option>
    <option value='16:00:00'>4:00 PM</option>
    <option value='16:30:00'>4:30 PM</option>
</select>
```

Is there any way to make it so that a user has to select a time for the CloseTime file that is at least 2 hours in the future from the ReadyTime field?

So if the user chose a ready time of 11 am, then the times in teh closetime field would start at 1pm (but still only go to 4:30).

I think this takes javascript from looking around, but i don't know that language at all.

Thanks everyone, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<label>What is the earliest Pickup time?</label>
<select name='PickupTime' onChange="updateCloseTime(this)" required>
  <option value='' selected='selected'>(Select a Time)</option>
  <option value='08:00:00'>8:00 AM</option>
  <option value='08:30:00'>8:30 AM</option>
  <option value='09:00:00'>9:00 AM</option>
  <option value='09:30:00'>9:30 AM</option>
  <option value='10:00:00'>10:00 AM</option>
  <option value='10:30:00'>10:30 AM</option>
  <option value='11:00:00'>11:00 AM</option>
  <option value='11:30:00'>11:30 AM</option>
  <option value='12:00:00'>12:00 PM</option>
  <option value='12:30:00'>12:30 PM</option>
  <option value='13:00:00'>1:00 PM</option>
  <option value='13:30:00'>1:30 PM</option>
  <option value='14:00:00'>2:00 PM</option>
</select>
<label>What is the latest Pickup time?</label>
<select name='CloseTime' id="CloseTime" required>
  <option value='' selected='selected'>(Select a Time)</option>
  <option value='10:00:00'>10:00 AM</option>
  <option value='10:30:00'>10:30 AM</option>
  <option value='11:00:00'>11:00 AM</option>
  <option value='11:30:00'>11:30 AM</option>
  <option value='12:00:00'>12:00 PM</option>
  <option value='12:30:00'>12:30 PM</option>
  <option value='13:00:00'>1:00 PM</option>
  <option value='13:30:00'>1:30 PM</option>
  <option value='14:00:00'>2:00 PM</option>
  <option value='14:30:00'>2:30 PM</option>
  <option value='15:00:00'>3:00 PM</option>
  <option value='15:30:00'>3:30 PM</option>
  <option value='16:00:00'>4:00 PM</option>
  <option value='16:30:00'>4:30 PM</option>
</select>

<script>
  function updateCloseTime(PickupTime) {
    var PickupTimeValueSplit = PickupTime.value.split(":");
    PickupTimeValueSplit[0] = Number(PickupTimeValueSplit[0]) + 2;
    var valueToFind = PickupTimeValueSplit.join(":");
    var selectCloseTime = document.getElementById("CloseTime");
    var optionsList = Array.prototype.slice.call(selectCloseTime.options);
    optionsList.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
      if (element.value) {
        if (Number(element.value.replace(/:/g,"")) < Number(valueToFind.replace(/:/g,"")) ) {
          selectCloseTime.options[index].style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            selectCloseTime.options[index].style.display = 'block';
        }
      }
    });

  }

</script>
```

Comment: okay to make it more complex.  Is there any way to add to the first field that they can't choose a time that is BEFORE their computer's current time?  if you want me to ask a separate question and notify you, i can, just let me know.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes try to create another question and notify me ;)

Comment: Hi @adil.hlimi, i have this question here that may be related, if you can help!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779987/create-a-select-field-with-time-entries-that-cant-be-before-current-computer-ti

Answer (score 1):

I've made this JavaScript code for you, and tried to comment it very well, since you say you're a beginner.

```js
//This function is called when the user chooses an option in the first form
function adjustForm(selectForm){
  
  //Get the value of the chosen option
  var optValue = selectForm.options[selectForm.selectedIndex].value;
  
  //Failsafe
  if(optValue == ""){return;}
  
  //Get array of options from second form
  var opts = document.getElementById("closeTime").options;

  //Iterate through every option from second form
  for(var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++) {
    
    //Failsafe
    if(opt.value != ""){
    
      //And test them against the chosen option from form 1
      if(parseInt(opt.value.match(/^0?(\d{1,2}):/)[1]) < parseInt(optValue.match(/^0?(\d{1,2}):/)[1]) + 2) {
        
        //If they match, the option is deleted
        document.getElementById("closeTime").remove(j);
        
        j -= 1;
      }
    
    }
    
  }
}
```

```html
<label>What is the earliest Pickup time? </label><select id="pickupTime" name='PickupTime' onchange="adjustForm(this);" required>
    <option value='' selected='selected'>(Select a Time)</option> 
    <option value='08:00:00'>8:00 AM</option>
    <option value='08:30:00'>8:30 AM</option>
    <option value='09:00:00'>9:00 AM</option>
    <option value='09:30:00'>9:30 AM</option>
    <option value='10:00:00'>10:00 AM</option>
    <option value='10:30:00'>10:30 AM</option>
    <option value='11:00:00'>11:00 AM</option>
    <option value='11:30:00'>11:30 AM</option>
    <option value='12:00:00'>12:00 PM</option>
    <option value='12:30:00'>12:30 PM</option>
    <option value='13:00:00'>1:00 PM</option>
    <option value='13:30:00'>1:30 PM</option>
    <option value='14:00:00'>2:00 PM</option>
</select>
<label><br><br>What is the latest Pickup time? </label><select id="closeTime" name='CloseTime' required>
    <option value='' selected='selected'>(Select a Time)</option> 
    <option value='10:00:00'>10:00 AM</option>
    <option value='10:30:00'>10:30 AM</option>
    <option value='11:00:00'>11:00 AM</option>
    <option value='11:30:00'>11:30 AM</option>
    <option value='12:00:00'>12:00 PM</option>
    <option value='12:30:00'>12:30 PM</option>
    <option value='13:00:00'>1:00 PM</option>
    <option value='13:30:00'>1:30 PM</option>
    <option value='14:00:00'>2:00 PM</option>
    <option value='14:30:00'>2:30 PM</option>
    <option value='15:00:00'>3:00 PM</option>
    <option value='15:30:00'>3:30 PM</option>
    <option value='16:00:00'>4:00 PM</option>
    <option value='16:30:00'>4:30 PM</option>
</select>
```

The script simply gets the hour of the option chosen in `pickupTime`. Then it gets the hour of every option in `closeTime`, and starts individually testing them against the `pickupTime` hour, to see if they are smaller than the `pickupTime` hour. If they are smaller, it means they should be removed from the options.

I could imagine the  `if(parseInt(opt.value.match(/^0?(\d{1,2}):/)[1]) <= parseInt(optValue.match(/^0?(\d{1,2}):/)[1]) + 2)` line is the hardest for you to understand. Really it just takes the values from the options, and converts them to numbers we can use for logical tests.

It takes something like this:

```
09:30:00
```

And turns it into this:

```
9
```

If you want to know what all that gibberish means (I'm not sure you know what regex is), [this website](https://regex101.com/r/lY2xY8/2) should explain just that.

Otherwise, please know that this script is only made to guide you in the right direction. I can already identify two big flaws in it:

1)
When JavaScript deletes the options, it can't get them back. So if the user first chooses a time late in the evening, but then changes her mind, and chooses something earlier, JavaScript will have already deleted the late options, and won't be able get them back. So you will have to store the different options somewhere else, so JavaScript can remember them, and insert them again if needed.

2)
Right now, JavaScript only looks at the hour. Meaning that you can choose 4:30 as `pickupTime`, and then still get 6:00 as a `closeTime` option. Maybe that doesn't matter to you, but if it does you will have to either do even more regex magic to include the minutes, or maybe convert them into timestamps instead, and then compare those.

I hope this helped you :D

Comment: so clear and thought out!  Thank you!  I will try this out and see what I get.  Thank you for the details too, I really appreciate them.