# Create a select field with time entries that can't be Before current computer time

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to add to the first field that they can't choose a time that is BEFORE their computer's current time?

```
<label>What is the earliest Pickup time?</label><select name='PickupTime' required>
    <option value='' selected='selected'>(Select a Time)</option> 
    <option value='08:00:00'>8:00 AM</option>
    <option value='08:30:00'>8:30 AM</option>
    <option value='09:00:00'>9:00 AM</option>
    <option value='09:30:00'>9:30 AM</option>
    <option value='10:00:00'>10:00 AM</option>
    <option value='10:30:00'>10:30 AM</option>
    <option value='11:00:00'>11:00 AM</option>
    <option value='11:30:00'>11:30 AM</option>
    <option value='12:00:00'>12:00 PM</option>
    <option value='12:30:00'>12:30 PM</option>
    <option value='13:00:00'>1:00 PM</option>
    <option value='13:30:00'>1:30 PM</option>
    <option value='14:00:00'>2:00 PM</option>
</select>
<label>What is the latest Pickup time?</label><select name='CloseTime' required>
    <option value='' selected='selected'>(Select a Time)</option> 
    <option value='10:00:00'>10:00 AM</option>
    <option value='10:30:00'>10:30 AM</option>
    <option value='11:00:00'>11:00 AM</option>
    <option value='11:30:00'>11:30 AM</option>
    <option value='12:00:00'>12:00 PM</option>
    <option value='12:30:00'>12:30 PM</option>
    <option value='13:00:00'>1:00 PM</option>
    <option value='13:30:00'>1:30 PM</option>
    <option value='14:00:00'>2:00 PM</option>
    <option value='14:30:00'>2:30 PM</option>
    <option value='15:00:00'>3:00 PM</option>
    <option value='15:30:00'>3:30 PM</option>
    <option value='16:00:00'>4:00 PM</option>
    <option value='16:30:00'>4:30 PM</option>
</select>
```

this is my current code and I think because i want it to be based on computer time not my server time it has to be in javascript not php.

I currently have 2 select fields.  The first is my pickup time and this is what i want users to not be able to choose anything earlier than the current hour based on their time zone.  I want the earliest pickup to be 8 am all the same as that's as early as pickups can be.

I hope his make sense.

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: i am so thankful you took the time to read the whole post and come back with that helpful comment on a typo.  Thank you.  Please note it was tagged correctly, but you probably saw that.

Comment: That's why I commented. You tagged as one thing but mentioned the other. If you were confused about the relationship (as many people are on SO) you will have struggled to find the solution you were searching for.

Comment: For what it's worth, restricting a time field based on the user's PC time doesn't guarantee they won't circumvent your restriction by changing their PC time.  Even if they're in a different time zone, you should determine a minimum date/time on the server because the server's date/time is your source of truth.  Your client side code can request that date/time from the server and enforce that as the minimum, effectively preventing the user from circumventing your restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<label>What is the earliest Pickup time?</label>
<select name='PickupTime' id="PickupTime" onChange="updateCloseTime(this)" required>
  <option value='' selected='selected'>(Select a Time)</option>
  <option value='08:00:00'>8:00 AM</option>
  <option value='08:30:00'>8:30 AM</option>
  <option value='09:00:00'>9:00 AM</option>
  <option value='09:30:00'>9:30 AM</option>
  <option value='10:00:00'>10:00 AM</option>
  <option value='10:30:00'>10:30 AM</option>
  <option value='11:00:00'>11:00 AM</option>
  <option value='11:30:00'>11:30 AM</option>
  <option value='12:00:00'>12:00 PM</option>
  <option value='12:30:00'>12:30 PM</option>
  <option value='13:00:00'>1:00 PM</option>
  <option value='13:30:00'>1:30 PM</option>
  <option value='14:00:00'>2:00 PM</option>
</select>
<label>What is the latest Pickup time?</label>
<select name='CloseTime' id="CloseTime" required>
  <option value='' selected='selected'>(Select a Time)</option>
  <option value='10:00:00'>10:00 AM</option>
  <option value='10:30:00'>10:30 AM</option>
  <option value='11:00:00'>11:00 AM</option>
  <option value='11:30:00'>11:30 AM</option>
  <option value='12:00:00'>12:00 PM</option>
  <option value='12:30:00'>12:30 PM</option>
  <option value='13:00:00'>1:00 PM</option>
  <option value='13:30:00'>1:30 PM</option>
  <option value='14:00:00'>2:00 PM</option>
  <option value='14:30:00'>2:30 PM</option>
  <option value='15:00:00'>3:00 PM</option>
  <option value='15:30:00'>3:30 PM</option>
  <option value='16:00:00'>4:00 PM</option>
  <option value='16:30:00'>4:30 PM</option>
</select>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var datetime = currentdate.getHours() + "" + currentdate.getMinutes() + "" + currentdate.getSeconds();
    var selectPickupTime = document.getElementById("PickupTime");
    var optionsList = Array.prototype.slice.call(selectPickupTime.options);
    optionsList.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
      if (element.value) {
        if (Number(element.value.replace(/:/g, "")) < Number(datetime)) {
          selectPickupTime.options[index].style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          selectPickupTime.options[index].style.display = 'block';
        }
      }
    });
  }

  function updateCloseTime(PickupTime) {
    var PickupTimeValueSplit = PickupTime.value.split(":");
    PickupTimeValueSplit[0] = Number(PickupTimeValueSplit[0]) + 2;
    var valueToFind = PickupTimeValueSplit.join(":");
    var selectCloseTime = document.getElementById("CloseTime");
    var optionsList = Array.prototype.slice.call(selectCloseTime.options);
    optionsList.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
      if (element.value) {
        if (Number(element.value.replace(/:/g, "")) < Number(valueToFind.replace(/:/g, ""))) {
          selectCloseTime.options[index].style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          selectCloseTime.options[index].style.display = 'block';
        }
      }
    });

  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the options of the first `select` box and set their `disabled` property to true if they exceed the wanted time.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var now = new Date('09/30/2016 12:12:23'),
        hours = now.getHours(),
        minutes = now.getMinutes(),
        pickup = document.querySelector('[name="PickupTime"]'),
        close = document.querySelector('[name="CloseTime"]');
  
    Array.apply(null, pickup.options)
         .forEach(function(option){
            var parts = option.value.split(':'),
                h = +parts[0],
                m = +parts[1];
      
            if (hours > h  || (hours == h && minutes > m)){
              option.disabled = true;
            }
         });
  
});
```

```html
<label>What is the earliest Pickup time?</label><select name='PickupTime' required>
    <option value='' selected='selected'>(Select a Time)</option> 
    <option value='08:00:00'>8:00 AM</option>
    <option value='08:30:00'>8:30 AM</option>
    <option value='09:00:00'>9:00 AM</option>
    <option value='09:30:00'>9:30 AM</option>
    <option value='10:00:00'>10:00 AM</option>
    <option value='10:30:00'>10:30 AM</option>
    <option value='11:00:00'>11:00 AM</option>
    <option value='11:30:00'>11:30 AM</option>
    <option value='12:00:00'>12:00 PM</option>
    <option value='12:30:00'>12:30 PM</option>
    <option value='13:00:00'>1:00 PM</option>
    <option value='13:30:00'>1:30 PM</option>
    <option value='14:00:00'>2:00 PM</option>
</select>
<label>What is the latest Pickup time?</label><select name='CloseTime' required>
    <option value='' selected='selected'>(Select a Time)</option> 
    <option value='10:00:00'>10:00 AM</option>
    <option value='10:30:00'>10:30 AM</option>
    <option value='11:00:00'>11:00 AM</option>
    <option value='11:30:00'>11:30 AM</option>
    <option value='12:00:00'>12:00 PM</option>
    <option value='12:30:00'>12:30 PM</option>
    <option value='13:00:00'>1:00 PM</option>
    <option value='13:30:00'>1:30 PM</option>
    <option value='14:00:00'>2:00 PM</option>
    <option value='14:30:00'>2:30 PM</option>
    <option value='15:00:00'>3:00 PM</option>
    <option value='15:30:00'>3:30 PM</option>
    <option value='16:00:00'>4:00 PM</option>
    <option value='16:30:00'>4:30 PM</option>
</select>
```

Comment: is there a reason to use this method over answer 1?  i'm not trying to be picky, i just don't know much about javascript.